# MySql : Create view JOIN get max and min value from child table

Tags: mysql, join, view, aggregate-functions

Say, I have table named 'member'

```
    id     name
 ===================
    a      John
    b      Frank
```

Member have 'login_activities'

```
    id     login_time     gol     member
==========================================
    1      2012-10-01      99      a
    2      2012-10-01     125      b
    3      2012-11-01     255      a
    4      2012-11-02     111      b
    5      2012-11-07     101      a
```

I want to create view that have information about when first time login and last time login of the members and also the 'gol' value only from the last login.

Is it possible?

I've tried many ways. One of my attempt:

```
CREATE VIEW   view_firstlast
     AS
          SELECT
               MIN(a.login_time) as first_login,
               MAX(a.login_time) as last_login,
               a.gol,
               b.name
          FROM
               login_activities a
                   JOIN member b ON a.member = b.id
          GROUP BY
               a.member
```

It does'nt get right result. The 'gol' value is from the first login.
How to do this?

---

Something important here: **MySQL doesn't allow subquery in create view**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ALMOST there.  You have the login times, but I would take it and get the last login ID too to simplify a re-join to the login activities table vs trying to do a join on user AND date/time field since I would expect a key on the primary key of ID and not necessarily on (member, login_time) -- however, for this query using the min/max on date grouped by member, I would DEFINITELY have an index on (member, login_time) for optimization.

```
SELECT
      m.Name,
      PreQuery.First_Login,
      PreQuery.Last_Login,
      LA2.GOL
   from
      ( select
              LA.member,
              MIN(LA.login_time) as first_login,
              MAX(LA.login_time) as last_login,
              MAX(LA.ID) as LastLoginID
          FROM
              login_activities LA
          group by
              LA.member ) PreQuery
        JOIN member M
           ON PreQuery.member = M.id
        JOIN login_activities LA2
           ON PreQuery.LastLoginID = LA2.id
```

Then, since the above works, but fails due to how MySQL implements views, you might need to do it with TWO views, such that

```
create view MemberFirstLastOnly
as 
select
      LA.member,
      MIN(LA.login_time) as first_login,
      MAX(LA.login_time) as last_login,
      MAX(LA.ID) as LastLoginID
   FROM
      login_activities LA
   group by
      LA.member
```

then another

```
create view MemberLastFirstFinal
as
    SELECT
          m.Name,
          MFLO.First_Login,
          MFLO.Last_Login,
          LA2.GOL
       from
          MemberFirstLastOnly MFLO
            JOIN member M
               ON PreQuery.member = M.id
            JOIN login_activities LA2
               ON PreQuery.LastLoginID = LA2.id
```

Comment: i get this error:
`#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause`

Comment: @TikasMamed, of course it requires a sub-query... I don't know an alternative to doing it without one.  If you run the query on its own, does it get you what you want?  Since I typically don't deal with VIEWs, I've never seen the error you are indicating.  You might get away by changing it to a stored procedure instead of a view (but that would restrict you from using it as a query-able table elsewhere.

Comment: yes.. you're right. it'is give right result. so, it's impossible to create view like i want to because it seems that in creating view not allowing subquery

Comment: Wow, good idea. Although Saharsh Shah have told to create 2 views, I never thought that it would be like this. Thanks alot, Drapp. it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW   view_firstlast
     AS
          SELECT
               MIN(a.login_time) AS first_login,
               MAX(a.login_time) AS last_login,
               a.gol,
               b.name
          FROM member b 
               LEFT JOIN login_activities a
                   a.member = b.id
          GROUP BY
               b.member
```

Comment: thanks. but it's not working. the 'gol' value still give from the first login.

Comment: which gol value you want to find

Comment: i want the 'gol' value is from the latest login

Comment: then you have to create 2 views. is it ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the login_activities table again, but using a special feature of mysql that allows you to get the whole row fir the max/min of another column:

```
CREATE VIEW view_firstlast AS
SELECT
    MIN(a.login_time) as first_login,
    MAX(a.login_time) as last_login,
    c.gol,
    b.name
FROM login_activities a
JOIN member b ON a.member = b.id
JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT gol, member
        FROM login_activities
        ORDER BY login_time desc) x
    GROUP BY member) c ON c.member = b.member
GROUP BY a.member
```